# Proving that $(A^t)^t=A$

Tags: proof-verification

$(A^t)^t=A$

$(A^t)^t-A=0$

$(A^t)^t-A=A-A\rightarrow (A^t)^t=A$

Is this proof is valid or do I need to add more information to make it more clear?

Comment: Is $^t$ transpose?

Comment: @user26143 Yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a proof. There is no argument, you just bring $A$ to the other side and then use what you're supposed to prove.

Let us denote the $(i,j)$th entry of a matrix $M$ by $M_{ij}$. Two matrices are equal if all their entries are equal.

$A^t$ is defined as the matrix with entries $A_{ji}$.

Thus 
$$((A^t)^t)_{ij}=(A^t)_{ji}=A_{ij}$$

so $(A^t)^t=A$.